# Downloading source via bazaar

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

Forgive me if this is a stupid question or an inapproptiate place to ask.

This is my first time attempting to download source by means of bazaar (launchpad).

Regardless of the package or branch... I always get an error like the following:

> bzr: ERROR: Revision
>   {package-import@ubuntu.com-20120711113620-v800iu2gzawm21xx} not
>   present in
>   "Graph(StackedParentsProvider(bzrlib.repository._LazyListJoin(([CachingParentsProvider(None)],
>   []))))".

I have looked all over and cannot find an answer. What does this mean? How can I resolve it?

Many thanks.

---edit---

Ubuntu 12.10 running BZR-2.6.0
Commands include but are not limited to:

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu/quantal-proposed/ubiquity
bzr branch lp:ubuntu/quantal/ubiquity
bzr branch lp:ubuntu/quantal/ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu
bzr branch lp:nano (just to test)
bzr branch lp:ubuntu/quantal/transmission (just to test)
```

Comment: which project? What's the full command you're using? Which OS?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error only for `lp:ubuntu/quantal-proposed/ubiquity` and `lp:ubuntu/quantal/transmission`, all the others worked for me.

I think something is wrong with the branches that cannot be fetched this way and you should ask whoever gave you the URLs to double-check if they are really supposed to be working.